# How to set Canvas background to allow clicks in a underlying iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, animate-cc

I've searched a lot of topics teaching how to prevent a whole Canvas element from receiving mouse clicks using the CSS `canvas.style.pointerEvents` property. But I only want to prevent the Canvas **background** from receiving mouse clicks.

I'm creating an application using Animate CC and CreateJS and I need one page to load several others inside of an iframe element. Everything is fine, I can load the pages, the background is transparent.

But nothing I tried allow me to click on the pages inside of the iframe because the Canvas I'm overlaying won't allow me to click through its background.

Here is my code:

```
this.createIFrame = function(page)
{   
    var iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    iFrame.id = "if";
    iFrame.setAttribute("src", page);
    iFrame.style.position = "absolute";
    iFrame.style.top = "0";
    iFrame.style.left = "0";    
    iFrame.style.width = "100%";
    iFrame.style.height = "100%";
    iFrame.style.border = "0";
    iFrame.style.scrolling = "no";
    iFrame.style.zIndex = "0";
    document.body.appendChild(iFrame);
    canvas.style.pointerEvents = "visible"; // I tried all possible values
    canvas.style.zIndex = "1";
}

this.createIFrame("page0.html");
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the canvas element must receive the mouse event to handle opaque/interactive content on the EaselJS stage, so clicking the "transparent" areas is not any different to the browser than the stage content.

The only way to handle both the canvas content AND content in an underlying iframe is to manually pass the event on to the iframe. This isn't simple, unfortunately -but you can look into generating mouse events manually. If your iframe is not on the same domain, your options will be limited. I have done this before using the `postMessage` API to safely send messages between the frames, but you have to implement the API on both sides.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi! Sorry for this long delay! Thank you a lot for the answer. I'll try this manual mouse event handling or I will try to use different Canvases for the elements of my interface. Thanks again!